# Boot loop data recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-nexus-s, clockworkmod-recovery, boot-loop

Cyanogen mod 9, ClockworkMod Recovery 5.8.9.2

I recently plugged in my phone after the battery completely died over night and the phone is stuck in a bootloop. I left it trying to boot for 30 minutes and it's just stuck.

I've made a backup in clockworkMod recovery and am willing to flash the phone to a newer or the same version of cyanogen but I don't want to lose data.

Is there any way I can make sure my contacts and SMS messages are recovered?

Comment: Before you go hard-core: have you checked with the [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for possible remedy? Have you tried to remove the battery for a few minutes, then re-insert and boot up again? Have you cleaned up cache and Dalvik-cache from CWM?

Comment: Yeah I did all of that. Battery out for a while. Cache clearing, everything I could find.

Comment: OK, was just a thought. Can you boot into recovery? Not sure if `adb backup` is available there as well, but you could give it a try then. For SMS, `com.android.providers.telephony` should be the one to backup, for contacts `com.android.providers.contacts` if I remember correctly.

Comment: @izzy can boot into recovery, no adb backup though :(

Comment: OK. Try `adb shell` and see if you can access e.g. `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts` (needs root). If so, you could at least `adb pull` the two directories and, if you flash the same ROM again or simply do a factory-reset, might be able to `adb push` them back, followed by a reboot so the corresponding services pick up the changed data. You could also try to `adb pull` the entire `/data/data` directory with settings etc. of all your apps, just in case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled android and lost all my data. Nothing else worked. :(

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through this, and it is possible to restore your data, take a look at my own experience at [Extract App Data from Nandroid / CWM Backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49707/extract-app-data-from-nandroid-cwm-backup). Basically you can use [Nandroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore) to restore the data you have backed up. But I am not sure if I got all the data of the apps that might have been installed to sdcard though, so if you can, take a backup including those apps as well (maybe too late now). Hope you still have that backup.. just noticed the date :(